# Emoji_Presentation doesn't match certain emojis in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

`\p{Emoji_Presentation}` is matching emojis like  (pizza), but not  (UK flag) or ‍‍ (family), presumably because they span multiple code points:

```
const regex = /^\p{Emoji_Presentation}+$/u

regex.test('') // true
regex.test('') // false in Node.js v18, true in v20
regex.test('‍‍') // undefined in Node.js v18 and v20
```

According to [InSync in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239060/emoji-presentation-doesnt-match-certain-emojis-in-javascript#comment136175833_77239060), the family emoji (‍‍) appears to fail, because it contains a [U+200D: ZERO WIDTH JOINER](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128).

Comment: Drop the `g` flag, then retry. Both should be `true`.

Comment: Thank you so much @InSync! That fixed it!

Comment: Actually, sorry, it only fixed it in Firefox for both emojis. I still get `false` in Node.js for .

Comment: [Can't replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qgh4.png) on Node.js 20.8.0. Please provide more information so as to make a [mre].

Comment: Thanks @InSync. See [Node.js 18](https://runkit.com/gnarea/emoji-matching) and [Node.js 20](https://imgur.com/q9R13qv).

Comment: The Node.js 18 link of yours output 2 `true`s. It seems that the last string contains a U+200D: ZERO WIDTH JOINER, which does not match `\p{Emoji_Presentation}`. Please edit the question so as to include the new information and submit it for review.

Comment: I mentioned the family emoji in the original question, I just forgot to add it to the code snippet. I'll add it now. Re: Node.js 18 code, [I only get `true` for the pizza emoji](https://imgur.com/uE45SZI).

Comment: As I said, that Node.js 18 outputs [2 `true`s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMOEW.png) for the pizza and the flag. `RegExp#test()` cannot return `undefined`; that's the return value of `console.log()`.

Comment: As posted here, there *appear* to be ***two*** ZERO WIDTH JOINERs in the family emoji, inbetween "", "", and "".

Comment: They can be positively searched for in any modern text editor by the regular expression `\x{200D}`. The notation is different in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) (and probably others):  `\u200D`

Comment: Thank you both! `/^\p{Emoji_Presentation}+(\u200D\p{Emoji_Presentation})*$/u` matches all three emojis.